# how to print '\u20ac' instead of the € in python

Tags: string, unicode, python-unicode

```
>>> x='\u20ac'
>>> x
'€'
```

Is there a way to print the string '\u20ac' directly instead of that euro sign? (on python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use double backslash.

```
x = '\\u20ac'
```

You're welcome.

Comment: It doesn't work on python

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Yes! The \ actually means “The next character is not a normal character.” But adding a \ before that will say: “This next character IS a normal character! Because -*- = +. Just add an extra \ in front.

“\\u20ac”

Comment: It doesn't work. When I type x in console, it prints out '\\u20ac'. Do you have any other solutions?